# Circuitikz - NC push button

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I want to add a normally closed push button schematic sign in a circuit. I'm a beginner in circuitikz and I couldn't find how to do it directly, only by modifying... Can someone help me?

[image: closed position]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with what you've tried so far.

Comment: How do you do it modifying, for example? (I don't know what this means, so I don't know what you're asking, but post what you have and it might be a bit clearer to somebody.)

Comment: Thank you. 
Well, here is a link where I saw how it is possible http://bonlacfoods.com/pdf/018827679.pdf 
but at the moment I'm kind of slow learner and did not manage how to do that. It is all explained, I know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a new component named `pushed button`.  I copied `pushbotton` and moved the bottom to `\pgf@circ@res@temp`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
%% Push Button
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/pushbutton/height 2}}{pushedbutton}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/pushbutton/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/pushbutton/width}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgf@circ@res@temp=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
  \advance\pgf@circ@res@temp by -2\pgfstartlinewidth
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@temp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@temp}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@temp}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfnode{ocirc}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
}
\def\pgf@circ@pushedbutton@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{pushedbutton}{#1}}
\compattikzset{pushed button/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@pushedbutton@path, l=#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[pushed button] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works perfectly.  When I grow up I want to be like you :))

Comment: The work if fine, but the pay is lousy.